# Как в в Java суммировать значение ключа во всех документах в коллекции MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

у меня есть коллекция в MongoDB

```
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("moneycar_db");
```

Пример одного из документов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я могу суммировать значение ключа, например,"money", во всех документах?